# AWS Lambda to revert back S3 "block all public access" if someone changed it to allow public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I'm trying to use AWS Lambda to check periodically (maybe use a cron job) if the S3 block public access is turned on. If it ever finds that S3 block public access is turned off (i.e, if S3 is public), the lambda needs to revert the setting back to "block public access". Not sure where to begin with this.. please advice.

Comment: First step would be picking the programming language you want to write the Lambda function in, then looking at the AWS SDK for that language. Please take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with the AWS SDK, and make some sort of attempt, then clarify your question on where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will get back if I'm stuck somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

S3 Block Public Access provides controls across an entire AWS Account or at the individual S3 bucket level. You could set it at account level and ensure that all users have policies that deny permission on the `s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock` action, as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyaccountbpa",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, be aware of the no-cost [Trusted Advisor option](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/aws-trusted-advisors-s3-bucket-permissions-check-is-now-free/).